# Silverado Hitch Install with Two Factory Arms

Tags: chevrolet, truck, silverado, trailer-hitch

What is this hitch looking bar with arms instead of a receiver?

I expected just the truck frame with weld nuts; or a hitch with a receiver. This looks like a hitch but two arms instead of a receiver.

Any ideas how to install a standard ball hitch into this strange looking factory hitch?

[image: two arms]
[image: looks like a hitch but no receiver?]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year and model of Silverado do you have?

Comment: Those are chain hooks (tie downs), originally used for transport from the factory.

Comment: Ahh, so the whole tube / hitch looking thing the two chain hooks are attached to is garbage and should be removed?

Comment: Thank you all. The hitch installed underneath the chain tie downs without any issues.